# Pickles and dump in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn the concepts of pickle in python. As per I know pickle is used to store objects in python and then we can access them in files. i wrote simple script for this but it is showing an error. I don't understand why

```
import pickle

plist= ["one","a","two","b","End!!"]
#p={'hi','hello','hola'}
file=open("pickle.txt","w")
pickle.dump(plist, file)
file.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "C:/Python33\pickle.py", line 6, in <module>
    pickle.dump(plist, file)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dump'
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `pickle.py` as a filename. It prevent to import `pickle` module of standard library. (The directory that contains the script is searched before the standard library path)

Rename `pickle.py` to other name, and make sure there's no `pickle.pyc` there.